# MySQL: How to display column name and row field value side by side

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 130+ columns and need to display the column names and the row field value for it side by side for record. Could someone help please me with the MySQL statement for it? The following will help clarify the output that I am looking for:

In Database:

```
A   B   C   D   E <- Column Name
1   2   3   4   5 <- Value
```

Output format needed in resultset:

```
Field - Value           
A        1          
B        2          
C        3          
D        4          
E        5
```

Using the following code, I was able to get the list of column names but don't know how to get the values associated with it:

```
SELECT c.column_name as qid
   FROM information_schema.columns c -- this has the column names       
   WHERE c.table_name = 'TABLE NAME'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your requirements as text, not an image. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to make a table with markdown.

Comment: Recommend handing the format of this in an application language as you can see below the implementation is verbose.

Comment: I think it might be time to question why you have a table comprising 130 columns and 1 row.

Comment: The table has more than one row. I just need to query for a specific record and display the result

Comment: It's still questionable why you have 130 columns, especially if you need to pivot it like this. It should probably be an attribute-value table in the first place.

Comment: You want to display... With what will display it -  php/Java/python?
Each one provide technique for executing a query such as  SELECT * FROM `table` .which will return array or object in format like 
Example of result for array 
`[
 0 => [column1 => value1, column2 => value2...],
 1 =>[column1 => value1, column2 => value2...],
 ....
]`

Comment: @Barmar You think? I thought you were more in the 'oh, just do 129 unions' camp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION`

```
SELECT 'A' AS Field, A as Value
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', B
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', C
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', D
FROM tablename
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', E
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. My table has 130+ columns in it, is there any easier way to get the output without having to have a select for every column in the statement?

Comment: Use a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get all the column names.

Comment: This feels very much like another step in the wrong direction